# Jena's getLocalName doesn't return numeric localname with Turtle

Tags: java, rdf, jena, apache-jena, turtle-rdf

According to the [changelog](http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#sec-changelog), the Turtle RDF serialization has supported numeric local names since August 2011.  In the following Jena code, the result of **getLocalName()** on the URI **http://www.foo.com/123456** is not **123456**.  Is this a bug in Jena?

```java
String turtle = "<http://www.foo.com/123456>  a  <http://www.foo.com/number>";
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel()
    .read(new ByteArrayInputStream(turtle.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), null, "TURTLE");

Resource foo = model.listSubjects().next();
String localName = foo.getLocalName();
assert localName.equals("123456");
```

Comment: Just as a note, you can get a resource a bit more simply with `ResourceFactory.createResource("http://example.com/123456")`.  You could make your test be `ResourceFactory.createResource("http://example.com/123456").getLocalName()`.  There's no need to parse and create a model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code does not indicate a bug.  The Turtle serialization may allow numeric local names but Jena's [**getLocalName()**](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Resource.html#getLocalName%28%29) "returns the name of this resource within its namespace."  That's a bit of an underspecification, since it doesn't say what "its namespace" is.  However, there's a bit of historical context, too. In the earlier RDF standards, from 2004, RDF/XML was the most common format.  In light of that, it's not surprising that the implementation of **getLocalName()** in **Node_URI** uses **Util.spltNamespace**, which is based on XML's concept of local names.  **Util.splitNamespace**'s documentation refers to finding an **NCName**, which is an XML concept:

> Given an absolute URI, determine the split point between the namespace
>   part and the localname part. If there is no valid localname part then
>   the length of the string is returned.
>
> The algorithm tries to find the longest NCName at the end of the uri,
>   not immediately preceded by the first colon in the string.
>
> @param uri
>   @return the index of the first character of the localname

Now, there is one other possible confusion here that it's important to address.  RDF is an abstract data representation.  An RDF graph (or model, as Jena calls them) is just a set of triples.  Turtle, N3, N-Triples, and RDF/XML are just *serialization* formats for RDF.  A Jena model can be serialized in lots of different formats, but it doesn't keep track of what serialization format its contents were read in from.  (Indeed, you can populate a model without reading triples from any file at all.)  That means that even though Jena will be able to *read* a Turtle file containing content like:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/>.
:12345 a :number .
```

the model won't know the IRI **http://www.example.org/123456** appeared in the file as **:123456**.  It's worth noting, as AndyS pointed out in the comments, that Jena's Turtle serialization *will* recognize that the IRI **http://example.org/123456** can be written as **:123456**, and will use that shortened version.

Comment: Good review of the situation.  Jena also prints out in Turtle as ":12345". getLocalName reflects the fact that RDF/XML used to be the primary format for "RDF 1.0" (RDF 2004).